# fopen and 'a+' mode in php?

Tags: php, pointers, fopen

Consider the code below (file `test.txt` doesn't exist):

```
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'a+');  
echo ftell($fp);  // 0  
fwrite($fp, "abc\n");  
fclose($fp);
```

I run the code once - `echo ftell($fp);  // 0`, I run the code again - `echo ftell($fp);  // 0` still returns 0. The file now contains *abc\nabc\n*, so I would assume it should return 3, since the file already contained *abc\n* before the second run.
If I would to run the code again and again, `ftell` still returns 0, why is that? I thought `a+` should put the pointer in the end of the file? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments at [php.net](http://php.net/ftell) already state the problem - so this is a known bug/behaviour.